# How to get the value from a table within a table with Lua?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I'm writing a material system for a game engine that I'm working where a Lua script is basically used as a config file for the material.

I'm storing values in a table, but for vector values (`vec2`, `vec3`, etc.) I am embedding a table inside the main table to hold the multiple values, like so:

```lua
material = {
    color = {0.2, 0.3, 1}
}
```

I want to get the individual values of `color`, and this is what I've tried to get the first value:

```c
lua_getglobal(L, "material");
if (!lua_istable(L, -1)) {return;};

lua_pushstring(L, "color");
lua_gettable(L, -2);
if (lua_istable(L, -1)) {
    lua_rawgeti(L, -1, 0);
    printf("%f\n", lua_tonumber(L, -1));
}
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

But it only ever prints `0.0`, no matter the first value in the `color` table. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first index should be `1` and not `0`.

```
lua_rawgeti(L, -1, 1);
```

Comment: Oh, thank-you. I didn't realize that arrays start at 1 instead of 0 in Lua!

Comment: Actually, indexes starts at 1 in Lua. In the C API of Lua using indexes, you also need to respect this convention, so the first index will be 1. You can still put a value at index 0 in Lua, but it is not recommended and some functions will not work properly.